# Check if the back up taken by onbar command in Informix database 12.1 is successful or not?

Tags: database, backup, informix

This problem made me vexed with **Informix**. When the same backup command has been issued with the `onbar` command by two different members of bargroup at the same time from different sessions and one backup has failed and the other back up is successful.  How can I identify which `onbar` command issued by a member is successful, using a technique which is based on ***bar_act.log*** file and not based on the return code of `onbar`?

Comment: Which storage manager are you using?  PSM, TSM, A.N.Other?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the `onbar -v` command/option to verify backups.  You can look at [`onbar -v`: verifying backups](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_231.htm) in the manual for more information.

```
onbar -v
onbar -v -w             # Whole system backup
onbar -v -f filename    # Spaces listed in file
onbar -v space1 …       # Spaces listed on command line
```

With options `-t time` for checking point-in-time recoverability, and `-p` for checking a 'physical only' backup.

Behind the scenes, `onbar -v` uses `archecker`.  You might need to use `onsmsync` too.

<sup>*I've not used this myself.*</sup>

Comment: Sir , good to see you again , while executing `onbar` it returns nothing , my point is if it returns a timestamp then we can verify it . How to supply exact time to `onbar -v` ?

Answer (score 1):

The bar_act.log contains the PID of the On-Bar process, so you can uniquely identify the process that failed.

2015-03-13 08:25:11 24098  24096 /usr2/gcastro/instances/gac1210fc5/bin/onbar_d complete, returning 0 (0x00)

Here 24098 is the PID of the main onbar process and 24096 the PID of the parent. The message always has the same format so you can parse it and ge the return code from it also.

Comment: how to identify which PID belongs to which user ?

Comment: After the backup has finished there is no way to recover this information. If for some reason you need to make a distinction on what user is executing onbar, you could modify $INFORMIXDIR/etc/onbar (since it is a shell script) and add some logging.
If you are afraid that your users may not execute diretly the onbar script bypassing the special logging then I believe your actual problem is in the realm of auditing.